# C# + MySql + SSL = "The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format"

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a MySql database from a simple .NET 4.0 C# console application:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MySqlTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(
                "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=my_database;Uid=my_login;Pwd=my_password;" +
                "CertificateFile=C:\\Users\\myuser\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\Sandbox\\MySqlTest\\certificate.pfx;" +
                "CertificatePassword=certificate_password;SSL Mode=Required;"))
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app, I get a System.IO.IOException: "the handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format".

I've created my .pfx file from 3 other files, first by running this command:

```
.\openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey user.key -in user.crt -certfile ca.crt
```

On a second attempt, I converted all three files to .pem and then run the same command (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-ssl.html - see "Creating a certificate file to use with the .NET client" section):

```
.\openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey user.pem -in user.pem -certfile ca.pem
```

I used the same three files to connect to the database from MySql Workbench and it worked. I don't know why I get this exception on my app.
Does anyone have any ideas?

I am using MySql.Data 6.9.6 driver downloaded from NuGet.

Thanks!